# Reusable React Pagination Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to create dynamic pagination react component with `reactstrap` as UI library. I am stuck around the problem of completing the same.

**UsersCard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import PaginationTable from './PaginationTable';



    export default class UsersCard extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props)

          this.state = {
              usersData: [],
              loading: false,
              per_page: 3,
              current_page: 1,
              total_data: '',
              currentPosts: []
          }
        }

    async componentDidMount(){
      await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              usersData: res.data.data,
              loading: false,
              total_data: res.data.data.length
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

        const indexOfLastPost = this.state.current_page * this.state.per_page;
        const indexOfFirstPage = indexOfLastPost - this.state.per_page;

        const currentPosts = this.state.usersData.slice(indexOfFirstPage, indexOfLastPost);

        this.setState({ currentPosts })

    }

    handleClick = (number) => {
      this.setState({
        current_page: number
      })
    }

      render() {
        const { per_page, handleClick, total_data, current_page, currentPosts } = this.state;

        return (
          <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {currentPosts.map(x => {
                return(
                        <React.Fragment key={x.id}>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{x.id}</td>
                                        <td>{x.first_name}</td>
                                        <td>{x.email}</td>
                                        <td>{x.last_name}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </React.Fragment>
                        )
                })}
            </table>
            <PaginationTable
                      per_page={per_page}
                      current_page={current_page}
                      total_data={total_data}
                      handleClick={handleClick}
                    />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

**PaginationTable.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pagination, PaginationItem, PaginationLink } from 'reactstrap';

const PaginationTable = ({ per_page, total_data, handleClick, current_page }) => {

    let pageNumbers = [];

    for(let i=1; i<= Math.ceil(total_data/per_page); i++)
    {   
        pageNumbers.push(
        <PaginationItem key={i} active={current_page === i ? true : false}>
            <PaginationLink onClick={() => handleClick(i)} href="#">
                {i}
            </PaginationLink>
        </PaginationItem>)
    }



    return(
            <Pagination aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <PaginationItem disabled={current_page <= 1}>
                    <PaginationLink onClick={()=>handleClick(current_page-1)}
                            previous 
                            href="#" 
                    />
                    </PaginationItem>

                        {pageNumbers}

                <PaginationItem disabled={current_page >= per_page - 1}>
                    <PaginationLink onClick={()=>handleClick(current_page + 1)}
                            next 
                            href="#" 
                    />
                </PaginationItem>
            </Pagination>

    )
```

}

export default PaginationTable;

My problems go like:

1) Reactstrap pagination UI is not showing properly.

2) Whenever I click on the `next` button, it consoles the error: `TypeError: handleClick is not a function`.

I am bit new to the dynamic pagination concept and am unable to identify the bug I am stuck with. Kindlt help to resolve the same. Any code improvements are also welcomed.

Comment: you have to pass `this.handleClick` from the parent component

Comment: It did got me rid of the click error but it's not working :/. Can you please help with that?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Can you help me out with this? Here is demo link : https://react-qxrpv8.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this approach:

1. `this.handleClick` has to be passed in from the parent.
2. `setState` function is asynchronous. So accessing the state right after setting it might not result in the same state you wish. To get around this React gives you a callback function as second argument. This is run only after the state is run.
3. You are not updating the `currentPosts` state after change in pagination. Pagination component is only concerned with changing page numbers, the change in data has to manually handled. You can handle this with:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          usersData: res.data.data,
          loading: false,
          total_data: res.data.data.length
        }, () => {
          this.formatData();
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  formatData() {
    const indexOfLastPost = this.state.current_page * this.state.per_page;
    const indexOfFirstPage = indexOfLastPost - this.state.per_page;

    const currentPosts = this.state.usersData.slice(
      indexOfFirstPage,
      indexOfLastPost
    );

    this.setState({ currentPosts });
  }

  handleClick = number => {
    this.setState({
      current_page: number
    }, () => {
      this.formatData();
    });
  };
```

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58900631?file=Hello.js)

Comment: That was big miss by me. Thanks a lot for this mate!

Answer (score 1):

About the first. You are trying to render just an array of jsx elements in `pageNumbers`. Instead of that - you could just push numbers into this array:

```
let pageNumbers = [];

for(let i=1; i<= Math.ceil(total_data/per_page); i++)
{   
  pageNumbers.push(i)
}
```

and then render pagination item directly where it should be using map.

```
{pageNumbers.map(i => (
  <PaginationItem key={i} active={current_page === i ? true : false}>
      <PaginationLink onClick={() => handleClick(i)} href="#">
         {i}
      </PaginationLink>
   </PaginationItem>
))}
```

About the second: `handleClick` is not a function because you are first defining it above the render function and then you are overriding it when destructuring state, but there is no such thing as `handleClick` in your state, so it is assigned to null or undefined.
All you have to do is remove it in destructuring assignment and pass it as `this.handleClick` and it should work.

Comment: Can you share more details what doesn't work now? How is it rendering? Or it is not rendering at all?

Comment: Can you please help to sort this out? https://react-qxrpv8.stackblitz.io